# Android CheckBox OnCheckListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if (b){
                editText.setText(nm);
                editText1.setText(ps);
                Toast.makeText(Page1.this,"Checkbox Remember me is " + String.valueOf(b),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying to make a login page which has two EditTexts and a CheckBox. I am trying to save login details in sharedprefrences when the CheckBox is checked.  In my code, I set the `OnCheckedListner` to know whether it is checked or not. But the boolean value `b` is always true...WHY?
Please Help me!

Full Code on Page1 activity :

```
public class Page1 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
EditText editText,editText1;
CheckBox checkBox;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MYSP", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String nm = sharedPreferences.getString("uname", "");
    final String ps = sharedPreferences.getString("upass", "");
    final boolean saveLogin = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("save",false);
    final boolean logout = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("logout", false);

    if (!logout){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Page1.this, ProfilePage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    final boolean[] isChecked = new boolean[1];

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if (b){
                editText.setText(nm);
                editText1.setText(ps);
                Toast.makeText(Page1.this,"Checkbox Remember me is "+ String.valueOf(b) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Page1.this,"Checkbox Remember me is "+ String.valueOf(b),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = editText.getText().toString();
            String pass = editText1.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            if (isChecked[0]) {
                editor.putString("uname", name);
                editor.putString("upass", pass);
                editor.putBoolean("save", true);
                editor.putBoolean("logout", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else {
                editor.putString("uname", name);
                editor.putString("upass", pass);
                editor.putBoolean("logout", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Page1.this, ProfilePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

ProfilePage Activity code :

```
public class ProfilePage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
TextView textView;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MYSP", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String n = sharedPreferences.getString("uname", "");
    final String p = sharedPreferences.getString("upass", "");

    textView.setText("Welcome "+ n + "    ");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("save", false)) {
                editor.putString("uname", n);
                editor.putString("upass", p);
                editor.putBoolean("logout", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else {
                editor.clear();
                editor.putBoolean("logout", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            textView.setText("Logout Success!");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: show full code please

Comment: According to your description, it seems like you have set android:checked="true" in your xml file. So make it false or remove that line and try again

Comment: Your full code says me that you should not have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code handles only the case `b = true`. Modify your code to include an `else` part like

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if (b){
                editText.setText(nm);
                editText1.setText(ps);
                Toast.makeText(Page1.this,"Checkbox Remember me is true",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           else{
                Toast.makeText(Page1.this,"Checkbox Remember me is false",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It still saying that value of b is always true in the if part and is always false in else part.

Comment: Are you getting any toast saying `Checkbox Remember me is false`?

Comment: @BoldX what are you expecting? It is true in the true part and false in the false part....

Comment: Leave it , I just want to save Login detail so that when the user check the remember me checkbox and so that  after logout the login details fill auto matically.

Answer (score 1):

This is your checkbox in xml:

```
                      <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/remember_me_checkbox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="left" />
```

This is your java code:

```
private CheckBox remember_me_checkbox;
private boolean isRemembered; //false by default

    remember_me_checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_me_checkbox);

    remember_me_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            isRemembered = isChecked;

        }
    });
```

Whenever user successfully logged in, you just save it in the preference. At the same time you have to save username and password as per your requirement.

```
SharedPreferences pref 
 =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(AppPreferences.PREF_FIREBASE_TOKEN, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("remembered", isRemembered);
            editor.commit();
```

And, next time when you come to this screen in case of logout. You will check whether isRemembered is true or not, if it is true then you get the username and password and set them to respective editTexts.

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(AppPreferences.PREF_FIREBASE_TOKEN, 0);

```
boolean remembered = pref.getBoolean("remembered", false);

if(remembered ){

//get the username and password from pereference and set to editTexts.
}
```

Comment: Now it saying savelogin is always true. savelogin is boolean type just like remembered in sharedprefrences

Comment: How are you saving savelogin key? can you please copy here.

Comment: No need to do that, I've done few tweaks now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have added OnCheckChangeListener in first place. You should have saved the credentials in SharedPreference when Login button is clicked by checking all the validation of email and password and checked status of your remember me checkbox.

Also in onCreate you must checked for isRemember value from SharedPreference and show put the values in Edittext accordingly.